# how can I parse a file adding a specific character based on coincidence?

Tags: file, parsing

I have a huge file like this:

```
#bedGraph section chr1:0-1024000

1000    0
2000    0
3000    0.003902
4000    0.070963
.............
```

the raw #bedGraph section chr1:0-1024000 is repeated along the file, but change chr1 to chr2, chr3.... what I would like to add to this file is "chrom=chr1" if the raw has chr1, "chrom=chr2" if the raw has chr1.. so the final result should be:

```
#bedGraph section chrom=chr1 chr1:0-1024000
```

As I am not a programmer, I would like to know if there is a fast & easy way to do this in linux or in pearl. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can use a simple regular expression. Try this (in a terminal):

```
perl -pe 's/ (chr.+?):/ chrom=$1 $1:/' {source file} > {target file}
```